# Node.js: update mongoDB document using mongoose.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema defined:

```
var bookCollection = new mongoose.Schema({

    book:[{
        bookTitle: String,
        bookOrder: Number,
        bookChapters: [{
            chapterTitle: String,
            chapterIntro: String,
            chapterOrder: Number,
            chapterArticles: [{
                articleTitle: String,
                articleIntro: String,
                articleOrder: Number,
                articleHeadings: [{
                    headingTitle: String,
                    headingOrder: Number
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]


});

var bookModel = mongoose.model('bookModel', bookCollection);
```

I then saved 1 document to mongoDB, this is the JSON object when checking using db.bookmodels.find()

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("530cc92710f774355434b394"),
"book": [
    {
        "bookTitle": "Javascript",
        "bookOrder": 300,
        "_id": ObjectId("530cc92710f774355434b395"),
        "bookChapters": [
            {
                "chapterTitle": "Functions",
                "chapterIntro": "All about javascript functions",
                "chapterOrder": 500,
                "_id": ObjectId("530cc92710f774355434b396"),
                "chapterArticles": [
                    {
                        "articleTitle": "A visual illustration of the JS function",
                        "articleIntro": "Something to see here, check it out",
                        "articleOrder": 500,
                        "_id": ObjectId("530cc92710f774355434b397"),
                        "articleHeadings": [
                            {
                                "headingTitle": "Parts of a function",
                                "headingOrder": 500,
                                "_id": ObjectId("530cc92710f774355434b398")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"__v": 0
```

}

If i want to change ***headingOrder*** to 100 instead of 500, how would i update the database using mongoose.js? I've been trying several things and i can't seem to get my head around it.

Everywhere you see examples with simple schema's but never with complex schema's like this one.

thx.

Comment: Do you want to update that value in _all_ `articleHeadings` of every book, all `articleHeadings` in this book (or this book's chapters) or only this one, the `articleHeading` with _id `530cc92710f774355434b398`?

Comment: It can't be done. Not that I can see - not in a single query anyway. I think you need to rethink the schema. One of the tenets of mongodb is to design your schema for your access patterns.

Comment: Are there any resources (articles) on good schema design in mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

You can always load the document in memory, made modifications, i.e. `book[0].bookChapters[0].chapterArticles[0].articleHeadings[0].headingOrder = 100` then [`save()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) it.

The example at the link above does exactly that, `document.find()` followed by `save()`.

Comment: is this the normal way of doing things, it seems pretty complicated and verbose?

Comment: How else would you distinguish that particular field, from another field like `book[1].bookChapters[3].chapterArticles[2].articleHeadings[16].headingTitle` ?